# BIDS, Standard and Enterprise Edition in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bids

1. Does SQL Server 2008 - Standard Edition (64-bit) support Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)? If yes, please let me know how to do it.
2. What are the main differences between SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition and Enterprise Edition? Is Standard Edition (64-bit) the same as Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1. Does SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition (64-bit) support Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)?*

Yes, the BIDS is a shared component available in all editions of "real" SQL Server (not Compact). I'm not 100% sure that it would be included in the Express edition - but definitely in the Standard edition, it's in there.

You need to select it at the time of installation (first item under "Shared Features):

[image]

> *2. What are the main differences between SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition and Enterprise Edition? Is Standard Edition (64-bit) the same as Enterprise Edition?*

**NO** - Standard edition is **NOT** the same as Enterprise edition - wouldn't make sense to have two editions that are the same......

There's an [extensive list on the Microsoft SQL Server site](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions.aspx) - too long to repeat here.

**Update:** to find out what edition you're database engine is, use

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

which returns something like:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) 
Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: Hi Marc_s, Thanks for you answers. I am trying to find out what editon does my sql 2008 have? SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Product Edition'. It is the right one?

Comment: Yes I got Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 <X64> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2). So it is a standard edition right?

Comment: @Mahesh: that's what the output says - yes - and I have no reason to doubt this output .....